# Queue manager for experiments in neural network training

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, queue, keras

I am conducting experiments with neural networks using Keras + TensorFlow backend. I do this using GPU on my PC, running Windows 7.

My workflow looks like the following.

I create a small python script that defines a model then runs `model.fit_generator` with ~50 epochs and early stopping, if validation accuracy does not improve after 10-15 epochs. Then I run a terminal with a command like `python model_v3_4_5.py`

Usually one epoch takes about 1.5 hours. During this period some new ideas (training parameters or new architecture) come into my head.

Then I create a new python script...

During experiments I've found that it is better not to train several models in parallel. I've experienced doubling of epoch time and strange decrease of validation accuracy.

Therefore, I'd like to wait until the first training finishes then run the second one. Simultaneously, I'd like to avoid idling of my PC and run a new training immediately after the first one has finished.

But I don't know exactly when the first training finishes, therefore, running commands like `timeout <50 hours> && python model_v3_4_6.py` would be a dumb solution.

Then I need some kind of a queue manager.

One solution that have come to my mind is installing Jenkins slave on my PC and use queues that Jenkins provides. As far as I remember, Jenkins has issues with GPU access.

Another variant - training models in the Jupyter notebook in separate cells. However, I cannot see queue of cell execution here. And this is a [topic, being discussed](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2340#issuecomment-333289131).

*Update.* Next variant. Add to the model scripts some code, retrieving current GPU state (does it run NN currently?) and wait if it is calculating. This will produce issues in case of several scripts (more than one bright new idea :) ) waiting for GPU to idle.

Are there any other variants?

Comment: What if you'd use docker?https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/docker  https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/

Comment: @RobertD.Mogos: sorry, I don't understand. Does docker enable any kind of a queue?

Comment: My bad, I should've explain more. No, it doesn't, but basically you could launch a docker per model. This way, by isolating the trainings into a docker  you might not encounter the decrease of validation accuracy

Comment: @RobertD.Mogos, does it run in Windows? It seems, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've come up to the simple cmd script

```
set PYTHONPATH=%CD%
:start

for %%m in (train_queue\model*.py) do (
    python %%m
    del %%m
)

timeout 5
goto start
```

One creates a subdirectory `train_queue` and puts scripts with models in it. All scripts log their output to files, whose names contain timestamps.

This script also calls [`timeout` program](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc754891(v=ws.10).aspx)